# Not able to run tests on remote host using Jmeter Distributed Testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, chromedriver, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to configure a distributed load testing setup for a browser based testing. Below are the settings used:

Settings Done on Client machine:

1. Made one change in `meter-server` file in `jmeter/bin` folder to add the Server host in RMI_HOST_DEF.
2. Chrome version: Version 112.0.5615.50 (Official Build) (64-bit)
3. Chrome driver version: 112.0.5615.28
4. generated rmi keystroke file from the Server machine and keep it in the client machine `jmeter/bin` folder.

Settings on Server machine :

1. Made changes in `jmeter.properties` file to add remote host IPs.

Now when we are trying to start the test, Chrome opens up on the client machine and gets closed quickly with the following warning:

> "You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP
> using something similar to
> `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.8.0` where the
> version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser
> you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as
> Selenium's."

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't provide enough details in order to be answered ASAP.

1. Run the test in [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) on the slave machine (without master) to see if it can be sucessfully executed. If it can run successfully - double check your [RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. You might want to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the WebDriver Sampler
3. Check [STDOUT/STDERR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for any suspicious entries

Answer (score 0):

From the warning message it looks like the Chrome Driver version used in the JMeter script is not compatible with the version of the Chrome browser installed on the remote machine.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Verify the version of the Chrome browser being used on the slave machine and make sure it is compatible with the version of the ChromeDriver being used.
2. Update the Selenium DevTools dependency in your project to match the version of the Chromium-based browser being used. You can find the latest version of the Selenium DevTools on the official Selenium website.
3. Restart both the master and slave JMeter instances to ensure that the changes take effect.
4. Try running the test again and see if the issue has been resolved.

If the above steps do not resolve the issue, you can also try the following:

1. Check the JMeter logs on both the master and slave machines for any error messages or stack traces that might provide more information about the issue.
2. Check the network configuration on both machines to ensure that they can communicate with each other properly.
3. Try running the test with a different browser or browser version to see if the issue is specific to the Chrome browser.
4. Try running the test with a simpler test case to eliminate any possible complications that might be causing the issue.

For more information on JMeter distributed testing, you can refer to the official documentation: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html.